# Why is my MLP-GRU model's train and validation accuracy is so low?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, vision

My task is action recognition where my inputs are mediapipe keypoints. I have 300 imbalanced classes. The first few classes have over 500 samples while the majority have less than 20 so I am using WeightedRandomSampler to deal with this imbalance. But even after that, my training and validation accuracy are still low.

I have tried the model below which is an MLP plus GRU model. My learning rate is 1e-06, learning step is 10, batch size is 32. After around several epochs, the accuracy is not reaching 1% and the train and val losses plateau.

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
  
  def __init__(self, num_classes, rnn_layers, hidden_size, fc_size):
    super(MLP, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.num_classes = num_classes
    self.fc_size = fc_size
    self.apply(self._init_weights)

    self.fc_pre= nn.Sequential(
                            nn.Linear(201, 100),
                           nn.ReLU(),
                           nn.Dropout(p=0.2),
                           nn.Linear(100, fc_size),
                           nn.ReLU(),
                           nn.Dropout(p=0.2))
    #Defines the number of features that define each element (time-stamp) of the input sequence
    self.rnn = nn.GRU(input_size = 150,
                hidden_size = 50,
                num_layers = 2,
                batch_first = True)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

  
  # initialize hidden state for RNN  
  def init_hidden(self, num_layers, batch_size):
             return (torch.zeros(num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).cuda(),
                     torch.zeros(num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).cuda())
  
   #inital hidden state made of zeros
  def forward(self, inputs, hidden=None, steps=0):
        length = len(inputs)
        # print('inputs size')
        # print(inputs[3].size())
        #Input data: RNN should have 3 dimensions. (Batch Size, Sequence Length and Input Dimension (the number of expected features which is 201)
        fs = torch.zeros(inputs[0].size(0), length, self.rnn.input_size).cuda()

        for i in range(length):
            f = inputs[i]
            #flattens the tensor
            f = f.view(f.size(0), -1)
            #print(f.size())
            f = self.fc_pre(f)

            # stores the tensor f in the sha pe [fs.size(0), fs.size(2)] to each “row” in fs to prepare for learning the sequence in RNN
            fs[:, i, :] = f
            # print('fs')
            # print(fs.size())
       
        #outputs : batch size, seq legnth, hidden size
        outputs, hidden = self.rnn(fs, hidden)
        #print(outputs.size())
        
        #the training code applies crossentropyloss as criterion which also applies softmax to the output so I don't have to use softmax here
        outputs = self.fc(outputs)
        
        #print(outputs)
        #print(outputs.size())
        
        return outputs

  def _init_weights(self, module):
         if isinstance(module, nn.Linear):
             module.weight.data.uniform_(mean=0.0, std=1.0)
             if module.bias is not None:
                 module.bias.data.zero_
```

Any suggestions for me? Thank you in advance

Comment: Test your models with 2 balanced classes to check if your models are wrong. I don't think that accuracy is relevant for unbalanced data by the way.

Comment: I am now getting around 86%  but I finetuned my parameters a little bit

Comment: It means there is no problem with your models. Maybe you can consider bigger models and a loss that takes into account of the unbalanced data. Most importantly: change your metric!

Comment: @ValentinGoldité what metric would you suggest in my case?

Comment: I don't know your problem. In general for classification I like the area under the PR curve on a meaningful band (not the whole curve but let's say between R=0.3 and P=0.3, depends on your curves). In your case I may average the values for each class i weighted by `e_i/sum_j(e_j)` where `e_i = 1/(5+sqrt(N_i))` where `N_i` is the number of images of class i. Then you have (prop to) 0.1 for classes with 20 data, 0.2 for class with 1 data, 0.03 for class with 500 data. It seems to be fair for me. It is an example you can consider a lot of things like that (based on F1 score for instance)